# How to react to your boss when there is a misunderstanding

Tags: resignation, relationships, conflict, manager

I was working as a waiter for 7 months when I decided to tell my manager and boss that I will be quitting the next month. I explained that the job hours were not helping with my school and the salary wasn't the best either.

My boss offered me a position with a new salary and new hours but they were not permanent. I told her straight forward that I was applying for other jobs and that if I got a day job I would take the offer so not to get excited.

We had an agreement that at the end of my 8th month of work I would stop. My boss decided to put me on the schedule for the month after that and went on vacation right after sending the schedule. 
I decided to take it up with my manager and explained that I was clear that I wouldn't work anymore after that given date and I had an interview and all went well. 
My manager told me to take it up with the boss but I had to wait a week, because they didn't have any way of contact.

I took the manager's word and sent a message to my boss the day after she arrived since my manager explained that she will be arriving in the evening. And I don't call or text anyone after 10 'o clock about work.

I explained to my boss how everything went and asked to see her in person. She was mad that I didn't take the offer and decided to stop answering me. 
So I went there personally to talk to her and explain again how everything went. 
My boss had a body language of someone who was not open to hear anything. 
I explained everything again and decided to give her my uniforms. My boss didn't take them from me and in return demanded me to come to work on the days she had scheduled even though I had told her that it was not possible and the manager knew this 2 weeks prior.

I also have to add that on various occasion I have also asked for a contract and did not get one. So I didn't sign any paper, yet I do have prove of all the times I did ask for one.

How should I handle something like this?

Comment: Did you put down your notice in writing? In addition, I have no idea what misunderstanding you are referring to in your post.

Comment: If you didn't sign any contract 7 months ago when you started, what is your obligation to stay there?

Comment: Did you get paid? If so, what's there to lose in just walking away?

Comment: What country are you working in?

Answer (score 5):

> We had an agreement that at the end of my 8th month of work I would
>   stop.
>
> ...
>
> How should I handle something like this?

It's not really clear what you are asking. But, as best I can tell, you should handle it by leaving.

You have given your notice. You have handed in your uniforms. So stop talking about it and just go.

Unless you are in a locale that requires some sort of relieving letter (which you haven't indicated), nobody can demand that you continue working past your notice date.

**Just leave.**